# Laravel Homestead using both Windows and Mac

Tags: php, git, laravel, vagrant, homestead

Following Laravel's 5.1 documentation about using Homestead on a per-project basis, I ran the commands to create a Homestead Vagrantfile inside of my Git repository for my project, I did this on my Macbook. Here is the Homestead.yaml for that:

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
hostname: projectname
name: projectname
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: "/Users/user/Sites/personal/projectname"
      to: "/home/vagrant/projectname"

sites:
    - map: homestead.app
      to: "/home/vagrant/projectname/public"

databases:
    - projectname

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
#       client-id: foo
#       client-token: bar

# ports:
#     - send: 93000
#       to: 9300
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

Problem is, after pushing this to Git and pulling down on my PC, the path in the Homestead.yaml file is now completely wrong so that it won't work...

How can I abstract the path from Homestead.yaml to an environment variable so that I can share a vagrant VM across operating systems?

Comment: I don't think that the solution Laravel docs describes was ment to be cross-platform friendly :) I'm sure it's technically possible to achieve what you need with some weird and cool hacks, but why not just set up separate Homestead environments and continue leading a happy coding life? As much as it would be great to know how to share the .yaml config, I have the feeling it's one of the situations where simple solution is the best solution.

Comment: My answer below works as a hack. The original reason for doing it this way is so that I can share my homestead setup with other collaborators.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Managed to solve it!

If I set the folder to `"."` it will use the current directory which works for both Mac and Windows!

```
...

folders:
    - map: "."
      to: "/home/vagrant/projectname"

...
```

Meaning now I have a Homestead vagrant machine in Git that I can use on both Mac and Windows :D

Comment: Can you please clarify where to put that `"."` (dot) you're referring to in the answer?

Comment: Under the 'map:' key under 'folders'